# error with apachectl restart

Tags: virtualhost, centos7, apache2

I'm trying to setup a virtual host. When I try and run `sudo apachectl restart` I get an error message.

Original error message:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Checking systemctl status httpd.service:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-04-28 08:52:35 CDT; 14s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 23763 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 23762 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23762 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

journalcte -xe shows:

```
No journal files were found.
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking at here and don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The `journalctl` command requires root privileges, otherwise you just get that misleading error message about no files being found.  It rarely has any useful error messages anyway. The best error message will be the one you got back from `apachectl restart`.  Could you include that in the question?

Comment: That makes sense. I've updated the question with the original error message as well. thanks

Comment: This seems like a configuration syntax error, which is possible since you were modifying the configuration while setting up a new VirtualHost. Using `sudo apache2ctl configtest` should guide you. "It parses the configuration files and either reports `Syntax Ok` or detailed information about the particular syntax error."

Comment: That error message you added is still a systemd error message, not an Apache error message.  Can you run `apachectl configtest`?

Comment: sry for the delay - `apachectl configtest` showed a few syntax issues so I'm going through these now. fingers crossed that'll solve it. Thanks for the suggestion!